# Using service as Model

Tags: angularjs, service, model, private, implementation

I want this service to behave as a Model.

```
angular.module('secrunApp').service('appState', function () {

  this.currentAnswerset = 1;
  this.currentQuestion = 2;
  this.name;

  function set(key, value) {
    console.log('>> set appStateModel', key, value);
    var localVar = key;
    this[localVar] = value;
  }

  function get(key) {
    console.log('<< get appStateModel', key, this[key]);
    return this[key];
  }

  return {
    get: get,
    set: set
  }
});
```

couple of questions.

1 - initially the default properties are undefined when starting the app and accessing this props. Why is that so?

2 - is this a simple but correct of handling a service as a Model and storing data to be accessible through out the whole application?

3 - I would assume by returning only a get/set API the rest of the properties aren't directly accessible (sort of private) but they aren't. Can someone explain why is that so?

Once injected into a Controller I set and get property value as follows, works perfectly.

```
appState.set('name', 'SJV');
appState.get('name');
```

General question: what would be a solid and correct implementation. I want to keep it simple, approachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

`.service()` expects a constructor function. Which Angular instantiates using the `new` operator. So, you do not need to return a new object. JavaScript returns the object for you. Now, in the service constructor function, you can add the public function to the `this` variable.

```js
angular
    .module('secrunApp')
    .service('appState', function () {
        this.currentAnswerset = 1;
        this.currentQuestion = 2;
        this.name;

        this.set = function (key, value) {
            console.log('>> set appStateModel', key, value);
            var localVar = key;
            this[localVar] = value;
        };

        this.get = function (key) {
            console.log('<< get appStateModel', key, this[key]);
            return this[key];
        };
    });
```

Now, your service instance is the reference to the same object that is referred by `this` within the service constructor function. But since your data is tied to the service object itself, they are not private yet. We come back to that later.

**Question 2**

You could try having a base controller higher up in the DOM, that handles all the app level view model. E.g.

```html
<body ng-controller="AppController as appVm">
  <div ng-controller="SomethingController as somethingVm">
    <p>{{ appVm.currentAnswerset }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Question 3**

To keep the variables private, defined a local variable in your service constructor, which only the getter and setter can access via closure.

```js
angular
    .module('secrunApp')
    .service('appState', function () {
        // Private data only getter and setter can access
        var data = {
            currentAnswerset: 1,
            currentQuestion: 2,
            name: ''
        };

        this.set = function (key, value) {
            data[key] = value;
        };

        this.get = function (key) {
            return data[key];
        };
    });
```

Comment: this is cool, working with the closure, i was looking for that. however i cant set nor get a value in (appState injected in) my controller via 'appState.set('name', 'SJV')'  -- must be a minor thingy I am overlooking?

Comment: The functions were named wrong. Getter was named set and setter was named get. May be that's why it was not working for you. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

this reference is referring to your service creation function, not the object you are returning.  This is an example with a fix.

```
var result = {};
result.currentAnswerset = 1;
result.currentQuestion = 2;
result.name;

function set(key, value) {
    console.log('>> set appStateModel', key, value);
    var localVar = key;
    result[localVar] = value;
}

function get(key) {
    console.log('<< get appStateModel', key, result[key]);
    return result[key];
}

result.get = get;
result.set = set;
return result;
```

Comment: this works like a charm, but i need private vars via closure like Prashant explains in his sample.